# How does SelectKBest() perform feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, scikit-learn

`SelectKBest(f_classif, k)`, where `k` is the number of features to select, is often used for feature selection, however, I am having trouble finding descriptive documentation on how it works.  A sample of how this works is below:

```
model = SelectKBest(f_classif, k)
model.fit_transform(X_train, Target_train)
```

The ANOVA F-value, as I understand it, does not require a categorical response.  (see `scipy.stats.f_oneway`)  It is computing the value between the features. Why does `f_classif` require the response?

How does `SelectKBest` actually achieve a ranking of features based on the F-value when there should only be one F-value for a set of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really more about `f_classif` than `SelectKBest`. It's to [drop duplicate labels](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L148); note the `np.unique(y)`:

```
X, y = check_X_y(X, y, ['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
args = [X[safe_mask(X, y == k)] for k in np.unique(y)]
return f_oneway(*args)
```

`f_oneway` still only gets passed the feature matrix, but a subset of it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code, that's really interesting.  I'm going to take a look and see if it makes sense.

Comment: So the f_classif version of the f_oneway function and the scipy version of the f_oneway function are coded slightly differently and are not directly comparable.  f_classif assumes more than one category and will treat features in each class as levels in a variable. Scipy assumes more than one level and treats each column (feature) as a level.  So it seems to me that f_classif is not a real ANOVA.  It also seems like ANOVA is discouraged for binary classification.  Is it better to just use rank-sum tests to perform feature selection in binary (or really any amount) classification cases?

Comment: I prefer $L_1$ or elastic net feature selection so I am unable to answer that question, unfortunately.

Comment: I probably shouldn't say ANOVA discouraged for binary classification, but with just two classes it is the same as doing a t-test.  Anyways, I've accepted your answer.